# Data binding failed after angular js upgrade

Tags: angularjs

I upgraded my angular js code from 1.2.26 to 1.3.12,and suddenly data binding failed.  I thought I followed the 1.3 style controller. Please advise

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<p>Try to change the names.</p>

<div ng-app="" data-ng-controller="PersonController">

First Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('PersonController', [funnction() {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
}]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a typo: "Contoller" instead of controller.

Second, remove the second `ng-app` from the div where you assign the controller. It causes an override of your first declaration.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SSZglJ5ymE6QhOAkmfJE?p=preview)

Comment: I didn't see the misspelled contoller. Removing the second ng-app still didn't resolve the problem. Can you check again？

Comment: Works in the plunker.

Comment: Thanks. And you are correct that I need to remove the second ng-app. But there is another problem. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

Mosho is correct that I should remove the second ng-app. But there is another problem. The bracket pair around controller should be removed.

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('PersonController', [function() {

    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
}]);
</script>
```

won't work.

After removing the braket

```
<script>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('PersonController', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
</script>
```

It started to work. I saw the bracket is required by [1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)